# Insert data in Vertex Buffer Object

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, vbo

I´m creating a template class in order to initialize a VBO and fill it with different kind of data, i.e. 2d vectors, 3d vectors, indices and so on.
Values are passed to the class constructor in a std:vector and then, as far as I know, all of them must be concatenated in a array of floats to push them into the VBO.

Lets say I have a 3d vector class like this:

```
class Vector3
{
public:
    GLfloat* Values;


public:
    Vector3(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
    {
        Values = new GLfloat[3];
        Values[0] = x;
        Values[1] = y;
        Values[2] = z;

    }

    ~Vector3() { delete Values}

    static int Size() { return 3; };

    ...
};
```

And then the template class with this constructor

```
template <class T1> class VBO
{
public:
    VBO(std::vector<T1*> v_array)
    {

        int s = T1::Size();
        GLfloat *map = new GLfloat[v_array.size() * s];

        int pos = -s;
        for (std::vector<T1*>::iterator it = v_array.begin(); it != v_array.end(); ++it)
            std::copy((*it)->Values, (*it)->Values + s, map + (pos += s));

        ...

    }
};
```

Now I can use 'map' to push data in the VBO using glBufferData

My question is. Is there a better way to do this? Say, is it possible to push std::vector v_array directly in the VBO?

Comment: You are using too many `new`s. For example use `std::array<GLfloat, 3> values` or even `GLfloat values[3]` if you must. Otherwise you are not deleting it correctly, your class is missing correct copy constructor and assignment operators and is inefficient.

Comment: In addition to @NeilKirk: When you use a std::vector<T1> instead of std::vector<T1*> you can use the v_array.data() directly. No need to copy anything.

Comment: @NeilKirk Please don´t be worried about the too many news. The class Vector3 is way more coplex and this is only an extract. In the original code everything is released when needed. Also std::vector<T1*> is an array of pointers (not Vector3 classes dinamically allocated). My problem is, lets say, I have two Vector3 classes being V1(1, 2, 3) and v2(4, 5, 6) and I need a monodimensional array of floats like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].

Comment: If you have each vertex scattered around in memory, with the passed array being pointers to them, then yes, you must copy each vertex into a contiguous array before uploading them. But 3D vectors are usually used as value types in languages that support them, so you shouldn't be storing an array of pointers to vectors.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Thank you. Sadly an array of pointers is what I have. I´ll live with it. Btw this is only my second question on stackoveflow and I´m already addicted to this community. You guys are awesome